# How to persist the image for Splash Screen in windows 8 app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, splash-screen

Currently I have set an image for the splash screen but when I restart my system it changes to the default image.

The image that I have set does not persist. Please guide me.

Also suggest me how can I design a new splash screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Splash image always persists after you install the app. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application. Also rebuild the project. The only design element you can give the splash screen is a `620x300` image and any background color to go with it. Apart from that you are not allowed to change anything.